# Running a VBS Script in Toad Data Modeller

Tags: vbscript, scheduler, toad

I was wondering if anyone out there can help me.

We are setting up a script that will go through each folder on a network drive and delete any files of a particular type, for example `.pdf`, that exist in the folder for longer than 300 days.

This script has been written in VBS but I want to use TOAD data modellers scheduler to execute the script. We use TOAD to schedule a lot of our queries and i want to keep it under the same architecture so that its easier to maintain. I can see there are two objects within the TOAD scheduler that might be of use: "Run Program" or "Run Script".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know nothing about "Toad" but "Run Program" sounds great. just call cscript.exe and give your vbs as parameter. that should run your vbs.

Comment: Yeah, "Run Script" means running SQL Script I suppose.   "Run Program"  means sound running external program as in Command Line.

BTw, "Toad" is different from "Toad Data Modeller".  OP, you are asking for TOAD or "Toad Data Modeller" ?